# Input Interface not being called on scene change in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

Unity 5.3.4 Version

My problem is when I am moving my character with 2 keys (diagonal motion) and I change the scene the character will cease to move in that direction and only move in the direction of the last key I pressed.

Example : I am moving up left (I first press the left key and then up key).  I then get transferred to another scene and (I am still holding down the up and left key) my character will end up only moving up until I let go of the left key and press it again.

```
void Update(){
    // Get a -1, 0 or 1.
    moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
    moveVertical = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

    // Check what is actually being called.
    print ("up : " + Input.GetKey("w"));
    print ("down : " + Input.GetKey("s"));
    print ("left : " + Input.GetKey("a"));
    print ("right : " + Input.GetKey("d"));
}
```

Is there a setting I can check to make multiple keys transfer over or is this a bug in Unity because even though I am holding down the left key the print statement will show false for 'left'.

Comment: What is the output of `moveHorizontal` and `moveVertical` when this happens?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain lets say I press and hold left first and then up making the character move in a diagonal fashion, moveHorizontal will be 0 and moveVertical will be 1 when I change scenes.  Resulting in the character only moving up.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question on the Unity Q&A site](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/414388/inputgetbutton-not-working-after-i-change-scenes.html) they ran in to the same problem as you, maybe you can use the suggested solution.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That wont work either as only one of the Inputs are being registered.  So even if I put checks for up and left only 1 will be put into play unless I am mistaken about something.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  Because the Input.GetKey() from my print() will just be in my if statements and from my testing they are not working as intended.